# Biblatex - Custom cite command neglects surrounding line spacing

Tags: biblatex, citing, line-spacing, apa-style

I use the following code to create a custom cite command for APA style citation of a table:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\sourcecite}
  {%\usebibmacro{prenote}
  }
  {%
  \mkbibquote{\printfield{title}} \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printnames[default][-\value{listtotal}]{author} \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \bibhyperref{\thefield{year}} \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \thefield{journaltitle} \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \thefield{volume}\thefield{number} \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{postnote} \setunit{\space(}%
  \bibhyperlink{\printfield{doi}}{\printfield{doi}}\setunit{)}%
  }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}
```

I use the command within a `tablenote` that is defined like this:

```
\renewcommand{\tablenote}[1]{\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
        {\small\raggedright\doublespacing
            \textit{\notelabel.} {#1} 
         }
         
    \end{tablenotes}}
```

The notes are printed in double spacing, but the citation is not (see screenshot).
[image]
Any ideas how to overcome this behavior?

Comment: don't show snippets, always show a small but complete example that can be used for a test. You are probably missing a `\par` after the `{#1} ` in your definition.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer, your hint was right! Sorry for the missing complete example.
Just out of curiosity: What does the `\par` do in that context?

Comment: spacing depends on the settings at the *end* of the paragraph, so you must end it before you close the group.